# Get current memory utilisation of a process running on a remote machine with WMI

Tags: memory, vbscript, wmi

I want to write a VB script that will return the current memory utilisation of a process on a remote machine.

I'm currently getting the info by greping the output of pslist.exe but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you use [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx). WorkingSetSize?

```
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colObjects = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each Item in colObjects
    WScript.Echo Item.Name & " - " & Item.WorkingSetSize
Next
```

When I ran this on my local system the WorkingSetSize looked equivilent to the Bytes of mem usage.  So you'd divide by 1024 to get Kb.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use WMI to remotly read performances conter on the remote machine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(VS.85).aspx