# How to know the CPU and memory usage of a process with WMI?

Tags: windows, wmi

I am using a wmi and python in order to track the behavior of the process running on my machine.

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
wmi = GetObject('winmgmts:')
processes = wmi.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

for process in processes:
    print process.ProcessId, process.Name
```

The Win32_Process has a [lot of information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx) but I don't see anything for tracking the CPU consumption. The window Task Monitor is showing this info so I think it is possible to get it.

I thought that the WorkingSetSize property is giving the memory consumption of the process but I can see different value from what is given by TaskMonitor.

How to get these 2 values for a given process?

Update:
Task Monitor shows the PrivateWorkingSetSize which seems to be not available with the Win32_Process. What is the difference betwen WorkingSetSize and PrivateWorkingSetSize?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want the WMI perf classes
[Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394277%28VS.85%29.aspx)  or
[Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394323%28VS.85%29.aspx)

E.g. their properties *PercentProcessorTime* and *WorkingSet*

Note that the Perf classes take a bit effort to understand.

- There are gotchas with the Formatted versions (See *Hey, Scripting Guy!* article [Why Does My Performance Monitoring Script Keep Returning the Same Incorrect Values?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/why-does-my-performance-monitoring-script-keep-returning-the-same-incorrect-values/))
- And the Raw Data classes need care to translate the "[CounterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394569%28VS.85%29.aspx)" into the right math formula to use to calculate the values based on the raw data. See [How's My Driving? Monitoring Performance Using WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974615.aspx) for a starting place.

But those WMI classes should give you all the info you're looking for.

Comment: It makes exactly what I want! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Please see:

- [WMI Made Easy For C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20150814043828/http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/wmi-made-easy-for-c/)
- [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Might also be of interest:

- [Get current memory utilisation of a process running on a remote machine with WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701904/get-current-memory-utilisation-of-a-process-running-on-a-remote-machine-with-wmi)

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. Unfortunately, this question doesn't answer my question. Is the cpu usage of the process available with the Win32_Process object?

Comment: "WMI Made Easy for C#" link appears dead.

Comment: Works now - thankee.  Hopefully it'll prove useful to others in their own googling. :)

Answer (score 1):

Win32_Process also has UserModeTime and KernelModeTime which can be used to calculate CPU usage

Also look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176718.aspx