# How can i get cpu usage of any application from java program using wmi query

Tags: java, wmi, wmi-query

How can i get cpu usage of any application from java program using wmi query.I use jacob api for accessing wmi.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the CPU and memory usage of a process with WMI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476018/how-to-know-the-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process-with-wmi)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here: [How to know the CPU and memory usage of a process with WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476018/how-to-know-the-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process-with-wmi)

Seems like 
`Select Name,PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process`

should work for you.